# Virtual file system in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual, fs

Is it possible to create a virtual directory in Node.js?

For example these are the contents of the root directory.

```
.gitignore
README.md
main.js
node_modules
package.json
```

When I start the node application will it be possible that it virtually creates a directory `xyz` in the root directory? This directory will not actually exist on the machine's file system.

As the node application is running, if any module (even `fs`) tries to read the file system it will see it like:

```
.gitignore
README.md
main.js
node_modules
package.json
xyz
```

I want to achieve this in Node.js only. And, the virtual directory `xyz` will also have files in it.
I have done a full search on Google, but could not find anything. Please, can someone help me?

Comment: If I search for the exact title of this question with a popular search engine, I find hits like https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs, https://github.com/Anarcroth/jayVFS and https://github.com/c9/vfs which may or may not be related to your question, but at least the first one seems to be related. There is also a https://www.npmjs.com/package/unionfs which may help with merging multiple, virtual and actual filesystems - at least that is what https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodefs suggests.

Comment: @tevemadar I thought of that, but no solution allows me to make it virtual in realtime. I can read the structure only using the special instances of the libraries. While what I want is that it becomes virtual and and even the `fs` module will see the structure without any hack/modification to the `fs` module. Thanks for the help. I have done my solution using a totally different idea which is not based on virtual file system. So, I am leaving this question for now.